# super fast median of matrix in OpenCV (as fast as MATLAB)

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, matrix, processing-efficiency

I'm writing some code in OpenCV and want to find the median value of a very large matrix array (single channel grayscale, float).

I tried several methods such as sorting the array (using `std::sort()`) and picking the middle entry but it is extremely slow when comparing with the median function in MATLAB. To be precise - what takes 0.25 seconds in MATLAB takes over 19 seconds in OpenCV.

My input image is originally a 12-bit greyscale image with the dimensions 3840x2748 (~10.5 megapixels), converted to float (CV_32FC1) where all the values are now mapped to the range [0,1] and at some point in the code I request the median value by calling:

`double myMedianValue = medianMat(Input);`

Where the function `medianMat()` is:

```cpp
double medianMat(cv::Mat Input){    
    Input = Input.reshape(0,1); // spread Input Mat to single row
    std::vector<double> vecFromMat;
    Input.copyTo(vecFromMat); // Copy Input Mat to vector vecFromMat    
    std::sort( vecFromMat.begin(), vecFromMat.end() ); // sort vecFromMat
        if (vecFromMat.size()%2==0) {return (vecFromMat[vecFromMat.size()/2-1]+vecFromMat[vecFromMat.size()/2])/2;} // in case of even-numbered matrix
    return vecFromMat[(vecFromMat.size()-1)/2]; // odd-number of elements in matrix
}
```

I timed the function `medianMat()` by itself and also the various parts - as expected the bottleneck is in:

```cpp
std::sort( vecFromMat.begin(), vecFromMat.end() ); // sort vecFromMat
```

Does anyone here have an efficient solution?

---

I have tried using `std::nth_element()` given in the answer of Adi Shavit.

The function `medianMat()` now reads as:

```cpp
double medianMat(cv::Mat Input){    
    Input = Input.reshape(0,1); // spread Input Mat to single row
    std::vector<double> vecFromMat;
    Input.copyTo(vecFromMat); // Copy Input Mat to vector vecFromMat
    std::nth_element(vecFromMat.begin(), vecFromMat.begin() + vecFromMat.size() / 2, vecFromMat.end());
    return vecFromMat[vecFromMat.size() / 2];
}
```

The runtime has lowered from over 19 seconds to 3.5 seconds. This is still nowhere near the 0.25 second in MATLAB using the median function...

Comment: Try out this algorithm: http://www.i-programmer.info/babbages-bag/505-quick-median.html. Sorting is at best *O(n log n)* but this site claims a median finding algorithm that is *O(n)*

Comment: I find it weird it takes such a long time using OpenCV. Do you take into account the time to read the data into a Mat ? What is the size of your input and your code ?

Comment: can you post your code? maybe you access elements in thr wrong order which gives you bad caching

Comment: Excuse me for the provocative question, but what's the point of finding the *exact* median of such a large array of floating point pixels? Other question: Do you have any knowledge on the expected range of values? Do your value span the complete range `+/-
std::numeric_limits<float>::max()`? Give some details about the input data, maybe it can be mapped to integer domain, when this problem would be easier/faster to solve.

Comment: I have added code snippets and information on my input image.  Thanks all for your comments and suggestions!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK.

I actually tried this before posting the question and due to some silly mistakes I disqualified it as a solution... anyway here it is:

I basically create a histogram of values for my original input with 2^12 = 4096 bins, compute the CDF and normalize it so it is mapped from 0 to 1 and find the smallest index in the CDF that is equal or larger than 0.5. I then divide this index by 12^2 and thus find the median value requested. Now it runs in 0.11 seconds (and that's in debug mode without heavy optimizations) which is less than half the time required in Matlab.

Here's the function (nVals = 4096 in my case corresponding with 12-bits of values):

```
double medianMat(cv::Mat Input, int nVals){

// COMPUTE HISTOGRAM OF SINGLE CHANNEL MATRIX
float range[] = { 0, nVals };
const float* histRange = { range };
bool uniform = true; bool accumulate = false;
cv::Mat hist;
calcHist(&Input, 1, 0, cv::Mat(), hist, 1, &nVals, &histRange, uniform, accumulate);

// COMPUTE CUMULATIVE DISTRIBUTION FUNCTION (CDF)
cv::Mat cdf;
hist.copyTo(cdf);
for (int i = 1; i <= nVals-1; i++){
    cdf.at<float>(i) += cdf.at<float>(i - 1);
}
cdf /= Input.total();

// COMPUTE MEDIAN
double medianVal;
for (int i = 0; i <= nVals-1; i++){
    if (cdf.at<float>(i) >= 0.5) { medianVal = i;  break; }
}
return medianVal/nVals; }
```

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I suggested.

Comment: @AdiShavit: Bravo for the answer. CV_User: You do not need to compute CDF for all bins, just compute till you reach 0.5 probability.

Answer (score 28):

Sorting and taking the middle element is not the most efficient way to find a median. It requires O(n log n) operations.

With C++ you should use [`std::nth_element()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) and take the middle iterator. This is an O(n) operation:

> `nth_element` is a ***partial sorting*** algorithm that rearranges elements in `[first, last)` such that:
>
> - The element pointed at by `nth` is changed to whatever element would occur in that position ***if `[first, last)` was sorted***.
> - All of the elements before this new nth element are less than or equal to the elements after the new nth element.

Also, your original data is 12 bit integers. Your implementation does a few things that make the comparison to Matlab problematic:

1. You converted to floating point (CV_32FC1 or double or both) this is costly and takes time
2. The code has an extra copy to a `vector<double>`
3. Operations on float and especially doubles cost more than on integers.

Assuming your image is continuous in memory, as is the default for OpenCV you should use `CV_16C1`, and work directly on the data array after `reshape()`

Another option which should be very fast is to simply build a histogram of the image - this is a single pass on the image. Then, working on the histogram, find the bin that corresponds to half the pixels on each side - this is at most a single pass over the *bins*.

The OpenCV docs have [several](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html#histogram-calculation) [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html#histogram-equalization) [on](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html#histogram-comparison) how to build a histograms. Once you have the histogram, accumulate the bin values until you get pass  3840x2748/2. This bin is your median.

Comment: I changed the medianMat using your suggestion. As the formatting is too limited in the comments box I will address it in an answer I will add.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - the comparison to Matlab isn't that problematic, as in Matlab the very same image was converted to double. Also, I only timed finding the median and didn't included all the conversions. Can you please type a short code snippet stating your suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Your original question used `std::sort` that is why I gave the `nth_element` suggestion.

Comment: I solved it! I will soon upload my solution as an answer. Thanks Adi!

Comment: `nth_element` is not an O(n) operation, it takes O(n log n) swaps.

Comment: Depends on the version you use. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element

Answer (score 7):

It's probably faster to find it from the original data.

Since the original data has 12-bit values, there are only
4096 different possible values. That's a nice and small table!
Go through all the data in one pass, and count how many of each value
you have. That is a O(n) operation. Then it's easy to find the median,
only count `size/2` items from either end of the table.