# opencv median calculation in java

Tags: opencv, android

There is a comment on here, on a stackflow post that answers the question of how to achieve super fast median calculation on opencv. The question is here:
[super fast median of matrix in opencv (as fast as matlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078756/super-fast-median-of-matrix-in-opencv-as-fast-as-matlab)

The problem is that the code is on C/C++ and I can't find a way to convert this to opencv for java or C#, since I'm trying to port this to OpenCV for Xamarin.Forms

Anyone knows how to conver this?

```
    double medianMat(cv::Mat Input, int nVals) {

  // COMPUTE HISTOGRAM OF SINGLE CHANNEL MATRIX
  float range[] = {
    0,
    nVals
  };
  const float * histRange = {
    range
  };
  bool uniform = true;
  bool accumulate = false;
  cv::Mat hist;
  calcHist( & Input, 1, 0, cv::Mat(), hist, 1, & nVals, & histRange, uniform, accumulate);

  // COMPUTE CUMULATIVE DISTRIBUTION FUNCTION (CDF)
  cv::Mat cdf;
  hist.copyTo(cdf);
  for (int i = 1; i <= nVals - 1; i++) {
    cdf.at < float > (i) += cdf.at < float > (i - 1);
  }
  cdf /= Input.total();

  // COMPUTE MEDIAN
  double medianVal;
  for (int i = 0; i <= nVals - 1; i++) {
    if (cdf.at < float > (i) >= 0.5) {
      medianVal = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return medianVal / nVals;
}
```

UPDATE:

As an example, this is my tried method on c# to calculate the mediam of a grey scale Mat. It fails, can you see what I did wrong?

```
        private static int Median2(Mat Input)
        {

        // COMPUTE HISTOGRAM OF SINGLE CHANNEL MATRIX

        MatOfInt mHistSize = new MatOfInt(256);
        MatOfFloat mRanges = new MatOfFloat(0f, 256f);

        MatOfInt channel = new MatOfInt(0); // only 1 channel for grey
        Mat temp = new Mat();



            Mat hist = new Mat();
        Imgproc.CalcHist(Java.Util.Arrays.AsList(Input).Cast<Mat>().ToList(), channel, temp, hist, mHistSize, mRanges); 
        float[] cdf = new float[(int)hist.Total()];
        hist.Get(0, 0, cdf);
        for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
        {
            cdf[i] += cdf[i - 1];
            cdf[i - 1] = cdf[i - 1] / Input.Total();
        }
        // COMPUTE CUMULATIVE DISTRIBUTION FUNCTION (CDF)

        float total = (float)Input.Total();

        // COMPUTE MEDIAN
            double medianVal=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                if (cdf[i] >= 0.5) {
                medianVal = i;
                break;
            }
            }
            return (int)(medianVal / 256);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to port that code to OpenCV java version? I think it's straightforward.

Comment: no, it's not. I already tried and the result I got was not the median but some random number. I passed it a grey image and got numbers in the thousands for the median (and a grey scale should not be more than 255)

Comment: I've just updated the question to include my version ported to C# that fails. This code runs on OpenCV for Xamarin.Forms